# android: using custom fonts in Galaxy devices

Tags: android, fonts, galaxy

I am using a custom font im my android application and i am applying like this

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"calibri.ttf");
    mEmailSignInButton.setTypeface(tf);
```

This code works perfectly in any device, except by the samsung galaxy note 2 (i presume that does not work in other galaxy device):

[image: typing something...]

Any clues of what can i do in galaxy devices?

Edit:

I doing like this right now:

This is my application class (overriding my default application class):

```
public class ApplicationCustom extends android.app.Application {

private static Typeface customTypeface;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "calibri.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "calibri.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", "calibri.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "calibri.ttf");
}
```

}

A class to override my fonts:

```
public final class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                                  String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {

    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                  final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

In my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="utils.ApplicationCustom"
```

Like was suggested, i boot my device...nothing happened, the final result is the same..

Any clues?

Comment: Do you see any stack trace about typefaces in logcat?

Comment: No, there is nothing regarding typeface in the logcat...

Answer (score 0):

basically if any devices theme overlapping your fonts than its not working because the device layer is come at last.you can reboot the device and than try it starts working ..because of boot theme will remove....